# how to run ubuntu desktop apps on android

Tags: android

I would like to be able to run ubuntu desktop applications on my Note 3 without rooting my device.
How do I do that?

running on Galaxy Note 3 N9005
Android 4.3

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a solution to run ubuntu applications on Android. Furthermore without rooting it.

The closer solution is ubuntu touch but it requires a complete install of the OS on your phone.